# Hybrid MVC/WebForms app, Forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms-authentication, asp.net-identity

**tl;dr**: I have an MVC application (using Identity) that we're importing some Web Forms pages (that were written for Forms Authentication) into. I need to know how best to protect those Web Forms pages using (existing) roles.

**More Detail**: We're actually rebuilding an old web forms app in MVC, and want to reuse some of the old Web Forms pages within the MVC app. We've put them in a subfolder within the MVC app, and got them running.

Most parts of the MVC app are public, but a few of the pages require authentication and authorization. For that, we're using the Identity Framework and the `[Authorize]` attribute, which behind the scenes consumes database tables that have the role information. Those database tables were actually used in the legacy app under forms authentication. That all works fine.

The difficulty is how best to use the same system of permissions on the Web Forms pages. I know that Identity can be implemented with Web Forms, though I'd prefer not to have a whole separate Identity Implementation. We could also just recycle the old forms auth system, though I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement that in an MVC app.

### What I've tried

#### Good ol' fashioned Forms auth

This is how we were managing security in the old app.

I put

```
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow roles="RelevantRole"/>
    <deny users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

in a Web.config file inside the directory containing the Web Forms. This does successfully redirect me to the authentication page, but after signing in, I get a redirect loop.

Comment: could you do this? I have the same case

Answer (score 0):

Your MVC Controller itself or individual methods can be attributed with the AuthorizeAttribute.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

You'll be able to find what you're looking for from this MSDN link.

Using this attribute will eliminate a need for the authorize stuff in your web.config as you've stated.

Comment: Can I use the Authorize attribute on Web Forms classes?

Comment: That would be like asking if you could use the authorize attribute on an entity framework class. I don't think that it was intended for that purpose as the MVC route engine wouldn't know to look at the classes authorize attributes without coding a custom onactionexecuted method that would reflect through and manually check the authorization

Comment: Technically though, you could but I don't think it will function as you intend it to. The purpose of the authorize attribute is to restrict users from different views instead of different models

Comment: Okay. I've updated the question to be a bit more clear. We're already using the `Authorize` attribute on the MVC controllers that need it. What I'm looking for is the most efficient means to secure the *Web Forms* pages with the same system of roles used by the MVC app. So, thanks, but that's not quite what I needed.

Comment: If you're looking for the functionality inside of a method or something, you should still be able to use Roles.IsUserInRole(User blah) and stuff like that

Comment: I don't really think that the authorization was intended to be used in that fashion so however you were doing your authentication previously would be the way to go.